# Chromium plugin directory location?

Tags: debian, plugins, chromium

I am trying to find the folder where Chromium stores plugins on Debian platforms. Does anyone know where this is?

Answer (score 4):

Seems like the correct directory for plugins and extensions is:

```
~/.config/chromium/Default/Extensions  # if you are using Chromium
```

and

```
~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Extensions  # if you are using Chrome
```

At least, that's the way it is in my Debian system.  Please note that `~` is your home dir.

You will have to see what extension is the one you are looking for, as they are named like this:

```
jim@debian:~/.config/google-chrome-beta/Default/Extensions$ ls -l
total 44
drwx------ 3 jim jim 4096 May 15 22:01 aohghmighlieiainnegkcijnfilokake
drwx------ 3 jim jim 4096 Apr  9 23:16 apdfllckaahabafndbhieahigkjlhalf
drwx------ 3 jim jim 4096 Apr  9 23:16 blpcfgokakmgnkcojhhkbfbldkacnbeo
drwx------ 3 jim jim 4096 Jun  3 18:56 cfhdojbkjhnklbpkdaibdccddilifddb
...
```

Comment: The default Debian folders in the given directory do not contain an extensions folder, only an "extensions states" folder: /home/pi/.config/chromium/Default/Extension State /home/pi/.config/chromium/Default/Local Storage
/home/pi/.config/chromium/Default/User StyleSheets Please update the post.